# What does it mean when a child span is longer than the parent span in Datadog trace flame graph?

Tags: apache-kafka, trace, datadog, apm, flamegraph

I'm struggling to interpret this output from a trace of a java service for kafka.consume in Datadog. I would expect the parent (kafka.consume) to span the entire duration of the child spans:

[image: Datadog trace flame graph]

You can see the kafka.consume is tracked as 14.9 s duration, but the child spans exceed that. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your program is written, but `kafka.consume` is likely running in its own thread. This trace indicates that `kafka.consume` triggered `MemberCosmosServiceImpl.getMe...` asynchronously and did not wait for `MemberCosmosService...` to return something.